# grub-install error: modinfo.sh doesn't exist

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub2, uefi

I entered the following command

```bash
grub-install --target=x84-64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootfloader-id=grub
```

But I get the error

> grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x84_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You have typos. It must be **x86** not x84. Also, it should be **bootloader-id** not boot**f**loader-id:

```bash
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=grub
```

Comment: I don't really see how this is going to help other people, it is not a question that can be reproduced, unless there is a typo in the person's command, which is a human error, not something that needs technical help. The error can be reproduced when the person does not add the target or directory, in which case a different answer would be helpful.

Comment: Lol, well, I actually just made the exact same typo, so glad it was here. ;-)

Comment: You have a typo too. It must be x86_x64-efi. The first dash should be underline.