# grub2-install Error: modinfo.sh Missing - Common solutions attempted

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I know this is a pretty common problem, but I've tried a bunch of common answers (enumerated below) to no avail.

Basic setup: I'm setting up a Fedora 31 / Ubuntu 18.04 dual-boot, each with a separate encrypted / and non-encrypted /boot partition, and a single /boot/efi partition for a total of 5. Installed Fedora first, then Ubuntu. All went smoothly, and I can boot into either from the efi boot menu. I'd like to lock the efi boot order and make the startup choice in grub though, and the current Ubuntu grub options missed Fedora. So I booted into Fedora and tried `grub2-install /dev/sda` to reset the MBR to Fedora's grub configuration and add Ubuntu. Instead I got the oh-too-common `grub2-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory`.

- I've tried [expanding the command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406030/grub-install-error-modinfo-sh-doesnt-exist) to `grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootfloader-id=grub2` with no change.
- I also tried [`dnf reinstall grub2-efi shim grub2-tools`](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1220066)
- And [installing](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1101352) `grub2-efi-modules`

Despite all this all I can find in my `/usr/lib/grub` directory is `arm64-efi` and `i386-pc` but no `x86_64-efi`. I'm a little out of my depth with this bootmgr stuff (my experience extends as far as hammering these problems until they work every time I have a new install).

Does anyone have a guess at what the problem is or another place to search for answers?

Answer (score 10):

First I ran "dnf provides" to find the right package:

dnf provides /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi

Then I installed the right package using its full name:

dnf install grub2-efi-x64-modules-1:2.06~rc1-2.fc33.noarch

Comment: This works for my CentOS 8 stream 

`dnf provides /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc

sudo dnf install grub2-pc-modules-1:2.02-99.el8.noarch`

Answer (score 7):

I could add the missing modules by installing `grub2-efi-x64-modules` package on Fedora.

In my case I had another error after that that "EFI variables were not supported on my system". I found another stackexchange post and could fix that by exiting the chroot environment and loading the efivarfs module by `modprobe efivarfs`. Then I logged back in into the mounted root  and mounted it via `mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars`.

Answer (score 4):

On ubuntu (this will create efi support in */usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi*)

```
sudo apt install grub-efi
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try

```
grub2-install --target=arm64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=grub2
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved by installing grub2-efi-modules and efibootmgr

Answer (score 1):

For deb system

```
apt install grub-efi-amd64-bin
```

for rpm system

```
dnf install grub2-efi-x64-modules
```

in my case it helped

Answer (score 1):

If your server supports both BIOS and UEFI modes, perhaps you tried installing grub-efi while it was in BIOS mode.  In doubt, check if `/sys/firmware/efi` is available on your system. If it isn't your machine is likely using BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I was on Ubuntu 20.04.1 live CD when I encountered this problem. I tried CodeAlfa's and A-la She's answers, but they didn't work.

Coincidentally, I had installed Artix Linux so I had the iso still on my disk. [`artix-base-runit-20201128-x86_64.iso`](https://iso.artixlinux.org/iso/artix-base-runit-20201128-x86_64.iso) image had the file `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh`.

I mounted rootfs.img (inside the Artix iso image) and copied the entire directory over:

```
mkdir /tmp/axi && mount artix-base-runit-20201128-x86_64.iso /tmp/axi
mkdir /tmp/rfs && mount /tmp/axi/LiveOS/rootfs.img /tmp/rfs
cp /tmp/rfs/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi -r
```

This solved the problem.