# Grub randomly stopped working, modinfo.sh doesn't exist, proxy stops yum install from internet

Tags: centos, boot, grub2, grub, uefi

So a couple days ago my Centos 7 installation just... decided to stop working.

I had left the computer on over a weekend.  There were no issues with it before I left it.  When I came back, the monitor and computer were still on, but the screen was just black (but with power, so not off).  I restarted, thinking the problem would go away.  Gets to the dell startup screen, then just... same issue, no grub boot loader. Just black.

I ran Dell's builtin hardware diagnostics tools, CPU, GPU, Ram and HDDs were all okay.  So unlikely to be an issue there.  I figured the power must have went out over the weekend or something, and caused issues. I used rufus to put the CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2003.iso onto my 32GB USB stick to try to repair my installation according to this site https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-reinstall-grub2-from-rescue-mode/.

running `df -h` states:

```
/dev/sda2/ mounted on /boot
/dev/sda1/ mounted on /boot/efi
```

I assume sda2 is for legacy/bios, and sda1 is for uefi.

At first I tried to install in Legacy mode (the USB was configured for BIOS and UEFI). after `grub2-install /dev/sda2` I got:

```
install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory
```

I thought, okay, I might need to use uefi.  So I rebooted, and tried again. after `grub2-install /dev/sda1` I got:

install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_x64-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory

So I thought "well clearly that's not where modinfo.sh is" so I tried to find it. Note neither this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406030/grub-install-error-modinfo-sh-doesnt-exist/406031#406031), nor [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593862) worked, it still couldn't find modinfo.sh.  So I typed in:

```
find / -name modinfo.sh
```

After a few minutes... Nothing.   So apparently this file just doesn't exist on my computer.  So I was stumped.  I checked my usr/lib/grub folder.  Nothing, it was empty. `ls -lrt = total 0`.

So I figured my final option was to try to use yum:

```
yum reinstall grub2-efi grub2-efi-modules  shim
```

Except there's one big issue with this.  My computer is behind a work proxy though I set up the certificates on the computer. But the only way I seem to  be able to "log in" to the network  is by opening up firefox and typing in my user name and password in the prompt it gives me to access it.  I have no clue how to enable this from the command line, though I believe some how I've been prompted through it before.  If I don't "log in" I can't access the internet.  So, predictably, when reinstall tries to access the internet, it fails and says things like "`could not resolve host: mirror.genesisadaptive.com; unknown error`" and every mirror fails.

So I seem to be stuck. Is there any way to un-screw this installation?

Comment: Well you could probably get centos mirror snapshot there by external media from where you can rsync it down... just in case, mind this: http://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1861977

Comment: @MichaelShigorin Wait, does this mean that my installation may have been fucked by a security update? Do I just downgrade and wait it out?

Comment: well I can't quite state that your system was secured a bit too much but a fscking botched update but there could be a chance to it... read the bug, they've posted recovery instructions here it seems: http://access.redhat.com/solutions/5272311

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: run

  ```
  find / -name modinfo.sh
  ```

  to know if the file exists or not.
- Step 2: if the file exists find its parent folder and copy all its content to the folder that system specify with errorr e.g `/usr/lib/grub/x86` ...
- Step 3: run

  ```
  grub2-install
  ```